# PDO prepared statements increment/decrement by bool

Tags: mysql, pdo, increment, decrement

In my POST file, I need to change the order of my items. I basically send a parameter called `moveDown` which is a bool, to check whether the item is higher or lower. So, I got this to get my parameter:

```
$moveDown = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'moveDown', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

I got another parameter for the item id. This is just a simple filter_input, nothing special.

```
$itemId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'itemId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Now, I need to use that variable to define whether to increment or decrement the order column. So I tried this:

```
$changeOrderStmt = $cmsDbh->prepare('UPDATE `items` SET `order` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
$changeOrderStmt->execute(array('`order` ' . ($moveDown ? '+' : '-') . ' 1', $itemId));
```

However, now the order column is 0. I really don't want to concatenate the query string and rather use PDO params. Is this possible or not?

Comment: naming a column order is just asking for trouble

Comment: I can change that to order, that's not really a problem. It's bad to use order and should've used order_num or order_id or something like that.